# AngularJs - how to check indexOf in a variable?

Tags: angularjs, indexof

I have this html code and if the "modalOptions.actionButtonText" contains "delete" then I need to display danger button instead of primary button

Html Code:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" data-ng-click="modalOptions.ok();">{{modalOptions.actionButtonText}}</button>
```

I know we can use "ng-if" to check the condition but is there any way I can use indexOf in angularjs or something else to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks dirty, but it works.

[See working demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/8FqlMPhAwguzhMLb709F?p=preview)

```
<button class="btn" 
  data-ng-class="{'btn-primary': modalOptions.actionButtonText.indexOf('delete') == -1,
                  'btn-danger': modalOptions.actionButtonText.indexOf('delete') > -1}"
  data-ng-click="modalOptions.ok();">{{modalOptions.actionButtonText}}</button>
```

The [ngClass directive](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angClass) lets you add/remove classes based on a boolean expression. So here, I am adding `btn-primary` if "delete" isn't found in the button text and `btn-danger` if it is.

Answer (score 2):

I wanted something similar, but wrote it in shorthand:

```
<li ng-class="haystack.indexOf('needle') != -1 ? 'active' : 'inactive'">
```